# How can I achieve this result using SQL select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-express

```
05214M  2   BRAKE PAD METAL EACH    1992    POLARIS 400 XC/ XCR 
05214M  2   BRAKE PAD METAL EACH    1991    POLARIS 400 XC/ XCR
```

Hello given the data above I am trying to take all rows that have the same part number (05214M) and the same model (POLARIS 400 XC/ XCR) and create a title using the years and model.

So I want the title for this one to be

```
BRAKE PAD METAL POLARIS 400 XC/ XCR 1991-1992
```

Is this possible using SQL?

Comment: Give us the table definition and maybe we can help.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Please, provide  the schema for the table and code you already tried. We are here to help solve the problem, not to solve them for you entirely.

Comment: Will there always be two rows? What if three or more - you want the min/max for the range?

Comment: The columns are as follow sku, num, title, year, model and I am using SQL server express

Comment: There will be more than 2 for some.. yes I am trying to take the min and max year and put the hyphen in between

Comment: My dear patrick post your table schema.

Comment: sample output as well

Comment: so what would you want displayed if it had 3 years 1991, 1992, and 1995?

Comment: I would want 1991-1995

Comment: @PatrickMahoney - which version of sql server express edition ?

Answer (score 2):

Use min max and group by

```
  select  model, concat( min(`year`) , '-', max(`year`))
  from  my_table 
  group by model
```

if you want a specific model you can  use a where

```
  select  model, concat( min(`year`) , '-', max(`year`))
  from  my_table 
  where model = '05214M'
  group by model
```

If you want a different result for model with a single row and model with more then a rows  you could use an union like this

```
  select  model, concat( min(`year`) , '-', max(`year`))
  from  my_table 
  group by model
  having count(*)>1 
  union 
  select  model, `year`
  from  my_table 
  group by model
  having count(*) = 1
```

Comment: Given response to 1991, 1992, and 1995 comment... up-voted.  This seems to address all the requirements and will actually work.  Other versions don't handle dynamic dates or use functions not available on sql server; or express for that matter.  (aside from missing `)` before updated)  and user will need to combine model + space + title or something and group by combined fields.

Comment: @xObert correct i use only .. standard sql  function

Comment: I only want to show the years it fits for a specific sku. How can I select the sku here as well?

Comment: I can't just do a where clause here because I want to insert new rows into a table. It should say sku then the model and the year it fits. If two different skus fit the same model then each sku should be its own row and there should be a row for each model that sku fits.

Comment: @PatrickMahoney   . I'm sorry but don't understand .. if is possibile try add a proper clear data sample and the expected  result

Comment: @PatrickMahoney  . i don't know if i understand correctly but i have add a new query  ..hope is usfeul

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you can't use a group by you can also do this with a windowing function like this:

```
SELECT model,
       CAST(min(year) over (partition by model order by year) as varchar(4)) + '-' +
       CAST(max(year) over (partition by model order by year) as varchar(4)) as Date_Range
FROM atable
```

Answer (score -1):

use concat and group by

```
select concat(item,' ',model,' ',Min(year),'-',Max(year)) as title   
from Table_name   
group by sku;
```

Comment: Think this will throw an error item and model must be in group by.  Don't think express supports mySQL's group by extensions.